# Attribute label 'Color' is not translated in frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes

on my [frontend](http://webshop.dagelijksegedachte.net.testbyte.nl/stoffen-vlinderhanger.html) the attribute label 'Color' is still in English. It should be in Dutch 'Kleur'.

In Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes > Color > Manage Label i put here also the Dutch translation 'Kleur'.

Why it's not translated in the frontend?

Thanks!

Comment: In frontend where its not showing in detail or layered navigation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check in your configurable product.

When you create the configurable association, you name the pivot and associate it with an  attribute.

In your case, I think you ave create your configurable product when the attribute was called "Color".

In the "associated products" tab of your configurable, the "Attribute Name" field of the Color attribute should be "Color" for now.

Change it to "Kleur"

Comment: now the only label i have is 'Kleur'. But it's still shows 'Color' on the frontend? Very strange..?

Comment: You maybe need to reindex your data